# How does R infer whether a variable is a datum or a vector in one expression?

Tags: r, function, vector, data-science

I am doing an online R data science course (dataquest). In it I am asked to perform functions on a data frame about the 2014 football world cup. Each row is an individual game. I am asked to create a function that takes the number of goals scored in each match and returns a vector where each datum is the percentage of total goals scored in the competition. The code (and certified correct answer is below)

```
goals_percen <- function(x){
    x/sum(x)*100
}

home_goals_percentage <- goals_percen(scores$home_goals)
away_goals_percentage <- goals_percen(scores$away_goals)
```

In python, I would have to have written something like

```
def goals_percen(series):
    total = sum(series)
    result = []
    for i in series:
        result.append(i/total)
```

Or some equivalent code using panda's `.apply()`

My question is how is the interpreter parsing the expression `x/sum(x)`? In order for the function to work it must treat the first `x` as an individual datum (or observation) and the `x` in `sum(x)` as the whole vector.

Comment: sum(x) is a scalar.  so x/sum(x) is just component by component the percentage that component is of the total sum.  Arguably simpler than the python code.

Comment: In R this is called "vectorization" (and I'm sure Python's pandas or numpy do something similar), where lots of operations R will automatically interpret at element-wise computations. For example, `c(1,2,3) / 5` tells R to divide each element by 5. Or `1:3 * 2:4` tells R to multiply each pair of elements in order.

Comment: I suppose there is also the element of recycling, where R will extend a shorter vector to the length of the longer, if possible.